# symfony doctrine repository generator creates wrong class

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I follow [this tutorial](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/repository.html) on how to generate Doctrine Repositories.

My entity `Event`:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as Serializer;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

/**
 * Class Event
 * @package AppBundle\Entity
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\EventRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="event")
 */
class Event
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="guid")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
     */
    private $uuid;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="parameter ""name"" should not be blank")
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="parameter ""description"" should not be blank")
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="parameter ""startDate"" should not be blank")
     * @Assert\DateTime(message="parameter ""startDate"" expects format of Y-m-d H:i:s")
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * @Serializer\Type("DateTime<'Y-m-d H:i:s'>")
     */
    private $startDate;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="parameter ""endDate"" should not be blank")
     * @Assert\DateTime(message="parameter ""endDate"" expects format of Y-m-d H:i:s")
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * @Serializer\Type("DateTime<'Y-m-d H:i:s'>")
     */
    private $endDate;

    // getters and setters left out

}
```

Following the tutorial above, I run

```
php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle
```

My expectation would be it generates a repository class `EventRepository`. Instead, it creates this:

```
namespace AppBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class AppBundle extends Bundle
{
}
```

I thought the generator would inspect the `repositoryClass` annotation in order to determine which class to generate. I tried using

```
php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle:Event
```

instead. Did not work.

I know I can just write the class myself, I merely wonder whether I use the generator wrong or just don't get the documentation.

Comment: try this command :
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle:Event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the answer here:

[Link to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115143/symfony2s-doctrinegenerateentities-doesnt-generate-repo-classes)

> If you have already generated your entity class before adding the
>   repositoryClass mapping, you have to create the class on your own.
>   Fortunately, it’s pretty easy. Simply create the class in the
>   Repository directory of your bundle and be sure it extends
>   Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository. Once you’ve created the class, you can
>   add any method to query your entities.